# Hang up Dialogflow telephony call using webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, ivr

I want to hang up Dialogflow telephony call using webhook. [This documentation says](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/phone-gateway)

> If you are using fulfilment, you can terminate a call by setting the
> `end_interaction` field of the [WebhookResponse](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1#webhookresponse) message.

I am using Dialogflow-fulfilment nodejs library. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add a response or list of responses to be sent to Dialogflow and end
> the conversation Note: Only supported on Dialogflow v2's telephony
> gateway, Google Assistant and Alexa integrations

`agent.end` will do the work to hang up the call.

You can use

```
agent.end('Thank you for calling')
```

The [issue](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/222) is still open,

If you update the  `dialogflow-fulfillment/src/v2-agent.js`, will work

```
 if (this.agent.endConversation_) {
      responseJson.triggerEndOfConversation = this.agent.endConversation_;
      responseJson.end_interaction = this.agent.endConversation_;
  }
```

Or you must be having access of response in your function then you can try,

```
return response.json({
    fulfillmentText: `Perfect I've got you down for  at , see you later!`,
    end_interaction: true
})
```

Comment: yeah I saw this but I couldn't find where to make changes. Where is v2-agent.js.

Comment: node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/v2-agent.js

Comment: Do we have to replace `responseJson.triggerEndOfConversation = this.agent.endConversation_;` with `responseJson.end_interaction = this.agent.endConversation_;`? because that's what the guy in the pull request did. He hasn't used both of the statements

Comment: need to keep both line

Comment: Do you think, fulfillmentText will convert it into audio? Can you hop over to my answer and see what fulfillment response Dialogflow support team have suggested to me?

Answer (score 0):

[I found a workaround](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/142) and it worked!

> send a follow-up intent from your webhook to the intent which has
> nothing other than end conversation switched on.

**Edit**

Besides, I talked to the dialogflow support and they said the fulfillment response will look like this to end the interaction:

```
{

"fulfillmentMessages": [{

"platform": "TELEPHONY",
"telephonySynthesizeSpeech": {

"text": "Goodbye!"

}

}],
"endInteraction": true

};
```